# Angular - How to link several typescript files with one template file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Imagine if you have a typescript file like the following one:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-alerts',
  templateUrl: './product-alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-alerts.component.css']
})
export class ProductAlertsComponent {

//code ...

//code (imagine several methods) that can the isolated from the rest

 calculatesAge(){
  this.age ...
 }

 checkIdPermission() {
  this.permission ...
 }

//

}
```

I would like to outsource these methods. However, the classes must inherit the properties from `ProductAlertsComponent`, as it would operate on/with them. So, in a separate file, I would do the following logic:

```js
//Separate file:
import {ProductAlertsComponent} from ".product-alerts.component.ts"

export class UserOperations extends ProductAlertsComponent {

 calculatesAge(){
  this.age ...
 }

 checkIdPermission() {
  this.permission ...
 }
}
```

But the template angular file (`product-alerts.component.html`) **would not** recognize `calculatesAge()` and `checkIdPermission()`. How could I solve it? It is not maintainable to have a ProductAlertsComponent class with several methods that could grow after years of developing. How could I link the extended class with the template angular file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the template is defined in the @Component decorator, not in the class itself. Therefore reusing the template is as simple as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-alerts',
  templateUrl: './product-alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-alerts.component.css']
})
export class ProductAlertsComponent {
// definition here
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-operations',
  templateUrl: '../product-alerts/product-alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-alerts/product-alerts.component.css']
})
export class UserOperations extends ProductAlertsComponent {
    thatOneMethodThatIsOverwritten(): void {
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I must to refactor the template file, as I suspected. I can't just inject more and more typescripts files that serves as a source to the same `component.html` file? For example, `example1.component.ts` serves method `example1()` and `example2.component.ts` serves method `example2()` to the same `example.component.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You can import those typescript file and use those methods like below

Import your typescript here.

```
@ViewChild('mytypescript') public mytypescript: ProductAlertsComponent;
```

Use the methods like this

```
this.mytypescript.calculatesAge();
```